# Filter data frame in r when string column value contains 'matching string'

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have data frame in following format

```
Question                Year
filter with question?   2010
keep this row           2009
keep this row too       2008
remove this one?        2007
```

expected results

```
Question                Year
keep this row           2009
keep this row too       2008
```

Get the subset of data frame excluding column Question contains question mark '?'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `grep` to filter out the `?` elements in 'Question' column

```
df1[!grepl('\\?', df1$Question),]
#           Question Year
#2     keep this row 2009
#3 keep this row too 2008
```

Comment: Cool. Works fine! Thanks. I am kind of beginner on r and most of the help online I found was how to get subset easily for numerical filter.

Comment: @Mutant No problem.  In cases where you need to find a pattern in a string, `grep` works fine.